# Deleting lines on a Python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm attempting to have the user delete lines when the right mouse button is clicked. I have binded a button 3 press event to the canvas, and passed that to the following function

```
def eraseItem(self,event):
    objectToBeDeleted = self.workspace.find_closest(event.x, event.y, halo = 5)
if objectToBeDeleted in self.dictID:
    del self.dictID[objectToBeDeleted]
    self.workspace.delete(objectToBeDeleted)
```

However nothing happens when I right click the lines. I have tested the dictionary separately and the line objects are being stored correctly.

Here is my binding:

```
self.workspace.bind("<Button-3>", self.eraseItem)
```

Per request some other snippets from the dictionary initialization

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    self.dictID = {}
... Some irrelevant code omitted
```

For the line creation I have two handlers, an on click and an on release which draws the lines between both the coordinates

```
def onLineClick(self, event):
  self.coords = (event.x, event.y)

def onLineRelease(self, event):
  currentLine = self.workspace.create_line(self.coords[0], self.coords[1], event.x, event.y, width = 2,     capstyle = ROUND)
  self.dictID[currentLine] = self.workspace.coords(currentLine)
  print(self.dictID.keys()) #For testing dictionary population
  print(self.dictID.values()) #For testing dictionary population
```

The dictionary prints fine here. 
Note that these are all functions within one class.

Comment: Your code (at least this function) looks fine. Is the event handler correctly bound? Try printing `objectToBeDeleted`.

Comment: And yes, it correctly prints the appropriate Canvas ID when I print after the variable assignment

Comment: Then I can only suggest you is to delete the item of the canvas before the conditional. But definitely this function hasn't any problem.

Comment: Putting the workspace.delete outside of the conditional work for removing the line, but now the dictionary is not being updated. I added a print statement to see if the conditional printed true and it printed false even though the line was deleted, any reason why this might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried making a working example based on your code, and now I know where is the problem: `find_closest` returns a tuple with one element if an item is found, so when you check if it is in the dictionary, first you have to retrieve the first element of the tuple.

```
def eraseItem(self,event):
    tuple_objects = self.workspace.find_closest(event.x, event.y, halo = 5)
    if len(tuple_objects) > 0 and tuple_objects[0] in self.dictID:
        objectToBeDeleted = tuple_objects[0]
        del self.dictID[objectToBeDeleted]
        self.workspace.delete(objectToBeDeleted)
```